# Inefficient jQuery usage

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code:

```
$( "#contact_seller .modal-content").addClass('has-error');
$( "#contact_seller span").empty();
$( "#contact_seller textarea" ).focus().after( "<span>Please be more precise about what You want to ask</span>" );
```

But Webstorm indicates, that this is inefficient jQuery usage. As much as I read, I need to ise .find() to make the code shorter. So I was thiking it needs to go something like this:

```
$( "#contact_seller")
            .find('.modal-content').addClass('has-error')
            .find('span').empty()
            .find('textarea').focus().after( "<span>Please be more precise about what You want to ask</span>" );
```

But obviosly this code isn't working correctly (I assume find() selects every next item, but I want it to slect parent element only).

How this code should be written correctly?

Comment: Just ignore Webstorm and use your origional code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to `end`, you can always...

```
var container = $("#contact_seller"); 
container.find(".modal-content").addClass("has-error");
container.find("span").empty();
container.find("textarea").focus().after("<span>Please...</span>");
```

Answer (score 1):

An `end()` call is missing. This should work:

```
$( "#contact_seller")
        .find('.modal-content').addClass('has-error').end()
        .find('span').empty().end()
        .find('textarea').focus().after( "<span>Please be more precise about what You want to ask</span>" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to write it like below,

```
var elem = $( "#contact_seller");
elem.find(".modal-content").addClass('has-error');
elem.find("span").empty();
elem.find("textarea").focus().after( "<span>...</span>" );
```

You can use `.end()`,  but this code would be more efficient as `end()` will do a reverse look up and it is an additional burden at your context.